# sendgrid substitutions not working

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

I'm just trying to set up a trial email for SendGrid, it's the first time I've used it so I'm sure this is simple, but I can't seem to get the placeholder data to replace.

I'm using NodeJS library like this:

```
sgMail.setApiKey(mailConfig.apiKey);

const msgConfig = {
  to: email,
  from: mailConfig.defaults.from,
  templateId: mailConfig.templates.registrationConfirmation,
  substitutions: {
    '--displayName--': original.displayName,
    '--companyName--': 'Hello world'
  }
};

console.log('Sending: ', msgConfig);

// now send the registration confirmation email.
return sgMail.send(msgConfig).then(() => {
  console.log('done.');
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.error(JSON.stringify(err));
});
```

And in the template there's a text block that I added using the visual editor:

```
Hello --displayName--

We would love to take this opportunity to welcome you to the store.

from

--companyName--
```

However when I run the test to send the email, it sends the mail okay, but doesn't substitute the placeholders.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51650080/variable-substitution-in-sendgrid-templates-with-nodejs-does-not-work/51653566#51653566), JohnnyMontana might be right regarding the "dynamic_template_data" tag instead of the "substitutions" tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try changing 'substitutions' to 'dynamicTemplateData'. Looks like they changed the name in the new version.

how i figured it out:
https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/master/packages/mail/USE_CASES.md

Answer (score 5):

It is not clear in Sendgrid documentation, but I think it is missing this line:

```
sgMail.setSubstitutionWrappers('--', '--'); // Configure the substitution tag wrappers globally
```

> Then remove dashes in **substitutions** object keys

Look at this link: [Sendgrid](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/master/packages/mail/USE_CASES.md#transactional_templates)

So, your code should be:

```
sgMail.setApiKey(mailConfig.apiKey);

// Configure the substitution tag wrappers globally
sgMail.setSubstitutionWrappers('--', '--');

const msgConfig = {
  to: email,
  from: mailConfig.defaults.from,
  templateId: mailConfig.templates.registrationConfirmation,
  substitutions: {
    'displayName': original.displayName,
    'companyName': 'Hello world'
  }
};
...
```

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 2):

For anyone NOT using dynamic templates, use Sendgrid's helpers as described here: [substitution use case](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/main/docs/use-cases/multiple-emails-personalizations-with-substitutions.md)

**IMPORTANT:** If using personalization helper, don't forget to set your `setSubstitutionWrappers` at the **PERSONALIZATION** level like so `personalization.setSubstitutionWrappers(['%%', '%%'])`.

If not using personalization, just set it at the global helper:

```
import mailClient from '@sendgrid/mail';
mailClient.setSubstitutionWrappers('%%', '%%')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const msgConfig = {
  to: email,
  from: mailConfig.defaults.from,
  templateId: mailConfig.templates.registrationConfirmation,
};

msgConfig.addSubstitution('%displayName%', 'Something to display');
```

It seems user given variables don’t work when you have the angle brackets <% ... %> around them, these are reserved for the <%body%> and <%subject%> tags.

So now you can make your template that might look something like this - **%displayName%**

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using Node.js library with V3 Version, this would help:

From Sendgrid Github docs:
**The default substitutionWrappers are {{ and }} in the node.js library**

```
const message = {
  from: {
    email: "from@example.com",
  },
  personalizations: [
    {
      to: [
        {
          email: "your email",
        },
      ],
      substitutions: {
        name: "hamza",
      },
    },
  ],
  subject: "Default Subject",
  content: [
    {
      type: "text/html",
      value: "Hey {{name}}",
    },
  ],
};
```