# Variable substitution in SendGrid templates with Nodejs does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-templates

Following the [USE CASE](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/master/packages/mail/USE_CASES.md#transactional-templates) on SendGrids github does manage to send me the e-mail with the correct template, but the substitutions does apparently not work, and is left blank in the resulting e-mail. Server side:

```
const sgmailer = require("@sendgrid/mail");
sgmailer.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
sgmailer.setSubstitutionWrappers('{{', '}}');

const msg = {
    to: '...',
    from: 'sender@example.org',
    subject: 'Hello world',
    text: 'Hello plain world!',
    html: '<p>Hello HTML world!</p>',
    templateId: '...',
    substitutions: {
        name: 'Some One',
        city: 'Denver',
    },
};
sgmailer.send(msg)
```

HTML in template:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
Hello {{name}},
<br /><br/>
I'm glad you are trying out the template feature!
<br /><br/>
<%body%>
<br /><br/>
I hope you are having a great day in {{city}} :)
<br /><br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Resulting email in my inbox:

> Hello ,
>
> I'm glad you are trying out the template feature!
>
> I hope you are having a great day in :)

Here the variables are clearly missing.
How do I substitute variables correctly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since what I was using was *dynamic* templates from SendGrid, I cannot use the "substitutions" tag, but must instead use the "dynamic_template_data" tag, see [this issue](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/issues/676). When changing the msg-object to

```
const msg = {
    to: '...',
    from: 'sender@example.org',
    subject: 'Hello world',
    text: 'Hello plain world!',
    html: '<p>Hello HTML world!</p>',
    templateId: '...',
    dynamic_template_data: {
        name: 'Some One',
        city: 'Denver',
    },
};
```

it works. This is not documented in the SendGrid-documentation as far as I can see.

Comment: "See this issue" links to the following GitHub-issue: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/issues/676

Comment: Ok Thanks i have one another problem when i am using "subject" 

in my msg array it doesn't write subject in email

Comment: Are you still using the templates? I am no expert here, but a solution could be having a {{subject}} variable in the subject field in the template, and then substitute it with the dynamic template data-field.

Answer (score -1):

Also you can do this:

```
import { getConfig } from '../config';    
const msg = {
                to: recipient,
                from: global.gConfig['SENDGRID_EMAIL_FROM'], // or getConfig().SENDGRID_EMAIL_FROM
                templateId: this.templateId,
                dynamicTemplateData: this.variables,
    };
```

getConfig.ts

```
export function getConfig(): any {
    return process.env;
}
```