# node.js sendgrid implementation

Tags: node.js, sendgrid-api-v3

I have followed the SendGrid docs in order to create dynamic transactional email.
But for somehow I could not assign the variables. They always returns empty.

```
const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail")
const SENDGRID_API_KEY = "deleted for safety, no worries i fill the right value here"
sgMail.setSubstitutionWrappers("{{", "}}")
sgMail.setApiKey(SENDGRID_API_KEY)

const msg = {
    to: "deleted for safety, no worries i fill the right value here",
    from: "deleted for safety, no worries i fill the right value here",
    subject: "Hello world",
    text: "Hello plain world!",
    html: "<p>Hello HTML world!</p>",
    templateId: "deleted for safety, no worries i fill the right value here",
    substitutions: {
        name: "Some One",
        city: "Denver",
    },
};
sgMail.send(msg);
```

**Template:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
Hello {{name}},
<br /><br/>
I'm glad you are trying out the template feature!
<br><br>
I hope you are having a great day in {{city}} :)
<br /><br/>
</body>
</html>
```

**Result:**

> Hello,
>
> I'm glad you are trying out the template feature!
>
> I hope you are having a great day in :)

Api keys are correct and the result is the mail I get. Can you guys tell me what I am missing?

Comment: I'm guessing you grabbed this example from [here](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/master/packages/mail/USE_CASES.md#transactional-templates). What I realized in your code is that you have `name` repeated in the `substitutions` property of the `msg`. Not sure if that might be the problem.

Comment: Yes i took it from there, and no it's just a typo. Thank you for pointing out. I've edited it.

Comment: It's been already answered over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51650080/variable-substitution-in-sendgrid-templates-with-nodejs-does-not-work), go and check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the latest version of @sendgrid/mail package and follow the instructions on
following link on official documentation
[Transactional Templates Use Case](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/master/packages/mail/USE_CASES.md#transactional-templates)

The thing is now you have to use dynamic_template_data instead of substitutions. You also can delete this line

> sgMail.setSubstitutionWrappers("{{", "}}")

because starting with v3 API, there's no need to specify the substitution wrappers as it will assume that you're using handlebars.

Here is an example that should work:

```
 const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
   sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
   const msg = {
     to: 'recipient@example.org',
     from: 'sender@example.org',
     templateId: 'd-f43daeeaef504760851f727007e0b5d0',
     dynamic_template_data: {
     subject: 'Testing Templates',
        name: 'Some One',
        city: 'Denver',
      },
   };

sgMail.send(msg);
```